# Bash - Parameter expansion for variable with leading white space

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable-substitution, bash-expansion

I keep wondering about strange rules of parameter expansion in shell.

If I declare

```
NUMBERS="  one   two   "
```

and if execute the following (note that there is no space between variable and the constant string.)

```
echo ${NUMBERS}'and three'
```

Bash (along with Dash and Kornshell) echoes:

```
one two and three
```

However, the same output is echoed with:

```
echo ${NUMBERS} 'and three'
```

I was under impression that according to [2.6.5 Field Splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_05) rules, 3a, the IFS whitespace should be ignored at the beginning and at the end of the input while expanding the `NUMBERS` variable.

Why does the shell at one occasion put the space between the expansion and the constant string and at other times not?

Comment: Simple answer is your quoting. You need to quote the variable name" `echo "${NUMBERS}'and three'"`

Comment: You are right. Quoting the variable name will indeed solve my problem. On the other hand, it will prevent Field Splitting with advanced IFS cases.

Comment: Quoting is important in most cases since file names in *nix can have spaces, newlines, special chars etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field splitting occurs *after* expansion, and `IFS` whitespace is ignored at the beginning and end of the *whole* input (to avoid creating fields before the first "logical" field or after the last one). Thus by the time it gets to field splitting, your first example is

```
echo   one   two   'and three'
```

which is parsed into fields `one`, `two`, and `and three`; likewise your second example is

```
echo   one   two    'and three'
```

which is also parsed into fields `one`, `two`, and `and three`.

Comment: Oh! I was under impression that the Field Splitting is applied piece-wise to the expansion results ("the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions").

So the Field Splitting starts at the `echo` and ends after the last apostrophe? 

And since there is no `IFS` whitespace before `echo` and after `three'`, this section does not apply?